# Relate many-to-many object without loading them from database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, insert, many-to-many

Suppose I have these classes, with a many to many relation between them:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual int IdClassA { set; get; }
    public virtual IList<ClassB> BElements { set; get; }

    ...
}

public class ClassB
{
    public virtual int IdClassB { set; get; }
    public virtual IList<ClassA> AElements { set; get; }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to insert a ClassB object and relate it to ClassA objects without bringing the ClassA objects from database, using NHibernate? (maybe just specifying a query to tell which ClassA objects are related to the new ClassB object?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options. Having two mappings for two classes one with the other class objects for inserts, and another one for just select without the objects.. Or making use of the eager loading (lazy true/false) which will retrieve the ids from the other classes but not the whole class.. it will be close to have nothing to load (just ids) in my opinion. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
var a1 = session.Load<ClassA>(idA1);
var a2 = session.Load<ClassA>(idA2);
var b = new ClassB { AElements = new List<ClassA> { a1, a2 } };
session.Save(b);
transaction.Commit();
```

`idA1` and `idA2` are the IDs of related `ClassA` instances. `session.Load` creates a proxy without loading the object from the db (or returns an already loaded instance, if there is one)